# My server addslashes automatically

Tags: php, cookies, server, addslashes

My server adds `slashes` in `cookie value`. Please help me to off this.

`current cookie value` is like this,

```
{\"pId\":\"7\",\"unit\":\"1\",\"uniqueId\":1430215177,\"color\":\"\",\"size\":\"\"}
```

But I want it to be like this,

```
{"pId":"7","unit":"1","uniqueId":1430215943,"color":"","size":""}
```

Comment: stripslashes - or spend some time on Google

Comment: please use this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3117830/724913

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent automatic add slashes while using parse\_str](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117512/prevent-automatic-add-slashes-while-using-parse-str)

Comment: Looks like you need to [turn off magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Comment: can i use Turn off magic_quotes_runtime

Comment: yes ... hobo sapieens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function available in php like this :

```
$jsonString = " {\"pId\":\"7\",\"unit\":\"1\",\"uniqueId\":1430215177,\"color\":\"\",\"size\":\"\"}"
stripslashes($jsonString);
```